# joda time plusDays forPattern("dd/mm/yyyy") does not switch to the next month

Tags: java, time, jodatime, days

```
DateTime start = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/mm/yyyy").parseDateTime("30/08/2012");
```

I added 10 days into start date above, but it does not switch to the next month. However, the code below will.

```
DateTime start = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").parseDateTime("30/08/2012");
```

Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing minutes (`mm`) and months (`MM`). From [the `DateTimeFormat` javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html):

```
 Symbol  Meaning                      Presentation  Examples
 ------  -------                      ------------  -------
 M       month of year                month         July; Jul; 07
 m       minute of hour               number        30
```

The same pattern symbols are by the way also used on Java SE's own [`SimpleDateFormat` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).